# Dynamic population of spinner with custom layout

Tags: android, spinner

I have a custom layout item for my listview. There is a spinner in the layout item which needs to be populated with values, usually by `android:entries`
The problem I have with this method is that the end user can't modify the values, which is something I would like to include. As the layout item and subsequently the spinner, is repeated multiple times on the same listview, I imagine there must be a way to populate it once, programmatically. I just can't figure it out.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customListItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exerciselbl" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Exercise"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/workout_items" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/repslbl" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Reps"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/reps_count" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/weightlbl" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Weight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So yeah, I want to avoid using `android:entries="@array/workout_items"` as this means manually typing out every single item for the spinner in an XML resources file AND I can't dynamically add items while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how it would be done, obviously the generics can change and there are other ways of loading the spinner.

```
public void populateSpinner () {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add("Item " + i);
    }
    adapter.addAll(list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

One of the more important lines is `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, this is because it tells the view that it needs to refresh the data associated with this spinner.

For more information, see the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) classes.

Comment: He speaks about the `Spinner` being in the row layout and your current code will not work for this. Also, the `add()` and `addAll()`(available with API level 11, if I'm not mistaken) already call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so the last call is useless.

Comment: I didn't realize ```add()``` and ```addAll()``` would ```notifyDataSetChanged()```, that doesn't appear to be documented in the API. I believe my example still holds true, with the exception of finding the spinner by that method. Instead, I think you would do something similar to:

```LinearLayout row = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1)).getItemAtPosition(position);```
```(Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);```

That said, I don't have time to test it right now, so it's just speculation.

Comment: Thanks for that, this is similar to the lines I was going along, I just couldn't get it working. Of key importance to this method is that the View has actually been initialised. Trying to find the spinner in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` or `onResume()` doesn't work as the view isn't visible yet...
The problem I find is that I would still have to do this for each Spinner in the ListView, I'm hoping for something more generic, like a Resource created in `onCreate()` that can be referenced by XML or something similar (I don't think that's actually possible...I've looked).